# Win7 not shutting down and not locking

Tags: windows-7, windows, reboot

Has anyone else experienced recently (and found a solution for)?

- *Windows SP1 64-bit not shutting down*; all icons are gone, the background image is still on the screen, the HD light is only flickering occasionally. I arrive at the office next morning and it's still this way ;-)
- *Lock screen no longer works*; either through the start menu or the <kbd>Win</kbd> <kbd>L</kbd> key combination

(I'm not yet sure that these always appear together).

Primary suspects are of course new software programs, updated drivers etc.

It is now 19 Dec 2014. Recent updates:

- No driver updates
- Flash player 16.0.0.235
- Paint.Net 4.0.5 - Does not autostart anything; usage makes no difference
- Mouse Recorder Pro 2.0.7.5 - Does not autostart anything; usage makes no difference
- BOINC 7.4.27 - Autostarts/screensaver. I see no issues in the [BOINC forum](http://boinc.berkeley.edu/dev/forum_forum.php?id=10) that apply. I have now disabled BOINC, let's see what that does.
- The December 2014 Windows updates

The updates that I see installed starting from Wed 10 December (i.e. from Patch Tuesday, given the time zone difference):

- 14 Dec KB2596764 Office Powerpoint 2007 security update
- 10 Dec 35(!) MS Office 2007 (Security) Updates. That can't be true, there were not that many and I always update. Control Panel/Programs/Installed Updates must show incorrect dates.
- 10 Dec 22(!) Visio (Security) Updates. Same issue.
- 11 Dec [KB3014406](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/3014406/en-us) Windows update
- 11 Dec [KB3013126](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/3013126/en-us) Windows security update
- 11 Dec [KB3009736](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/3009736/en-us) Windows hotfix
- 11 Dec [KB2952664](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2952664/en-us) Windows update
- 10 Dec [KB3006625](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/3006625/en-us) Windows update
- 10 Dec [KB3006121](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/3006121/en-us) Windows update
- 10 Dec [KB3013410](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/3013410/en-us) Windows update

I remember there was an out of bound update (which I applied) for an issue with an earlier one that made booting fail on some machines. That is my primary suspect, but I can't refind the exact information.

Background: [Microsoft Security Bulletins For December 2014](http://www.ghacks.net/2014/12/09/microsoft-security-bulletins-for-december-2014/)

As you can see, I'm still investigating, but I am asking here in case anyone has already found the reason and the solution.

Comment: Can you try another user account? Is there something in the eventlog?

Comment: Can you still start the task manager and try to kill process by process?

Comment: If you suspect it's the updates then use System Restore to go back to a point before you installed them and see if it makes a difference.  Otherwise, have you done and CHKDSK and SFC to check for file corruption yet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the reason, almost by accident, because it was hard to trace:

An install of a new version of [BOINC](http://boinc.berkeley.edu/) (in my case the new version 7.4.36) causes the issue.
After several reboots (not just one, strangely enough) it is gone.

I have now reported this [in the BOINC forum](http://boinc.berkeley.edu/dev/forum_thread.php?id=9948).